# How to change the legend names in a plotly bar graph in Python

Tags: python, plotly, histogram

I have a bar graph that looks like this -

[image]

As you can see the legend shows 0 and 1. I want to change this to show "Didn't Survive" and "Survived". For this I tried adding the code below in the `px.histogram` function but it didn't change the output -

```
labels = {0:"Didn't Survive", 1:"Survived"}
```

My original code is similar to this -

```
survivor = px.histogram(data_frame = train_df, x = "Survived", title = "Survivor Data")
survivor.update_layout(bargap = 0.6)
```

I am working on the [Titanic dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/titanic/data).

Answer (score 1):

Legends for `px.histogram` (`color=""`, actually) are auto-generated from your data.

I guess in your df 0 = dead and 1 = survived, or the opposite.

So you have 2 solution:

1. You completely rename/replace values in your original df

or

2. You "hack/trick" px with a new fake column which will be a copy of the one you want to use the column name and values for the legend title and legend labels:

For example, let's take a generic plot:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.histogram(df, x="total_bill", color="time")
fig.show()
```

*Click the pic to zoom in*
[image]

You see, because I set `color=""` on the column "time", I get its name/values for legend title/lables = time:dinner:lunch.

Because the df look like this:

| index | total_bill | tip | sex | smoker | day | time | size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 16.99 | 1.01 | Female | No | Sun | Dinner | 2 |
| 1 | 10.34 | 1.66 | Male | No | Sun | Dinner | 3 |

...

| index | total_bill | tip | sex | smoker | day | time | size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 86 | 13.03 | 2.0 | Male | No | Thur | Lunch | 2 |
| 87 | 18.28 | 4.0 | Male | No | Thur | Lunch | 2 |

So what I do, it's copying the desired column form original df into a new column, then replace all the data, so for my df it will:

```
df['test'] = df['time']
df['test'] = df['test'].replace({'Dinner': 'Test1', 'Lunch': 'Test2'})
df
```

| index | total_bill | tip | sex | smoker | day | time | size | test |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 16.99 | 1.01 | Female | No | Sun | Dinner | 2 | Test1 |
| 1 | 10.34 | 1.66 | Male | No | Sun | Dinner | 3 | Test1 |

...

| index | total_bill | tip | sex | smoker | day | time | size | test |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 86 | 13.03 | 2.0 | Male | No | Thur | Lunch | 2 | Test2 |
| 87 | 18.28 | 4.0 | Male | No | Thur | Lunch | 2 | Test2 |

**AND NOW** if I generate my plot again this is what it shows:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.histogram(df, x="total_bill", color="test")
fig.show()
```

*And voilà! (click on it to zoom...)*
[image]

**Note:**

This is the trick I'm using, if you find something official, let me know because I didn't find anything :)

Long explanation but 2 lines of code actually ;)